# Invalid InitialRouteName 'Loading'. Should be one of 'Profile', 'Main', 'History'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My BottomTabNavigator is working as expected. The problem is that I would like to initially render a page that is outside of the navigator tabs. How could I accomplish this?

```
import Loading from "./components/Loading.js";
import Profile from "./components/Profile.js";
import History from "./components/History.js";
import Main from "./components/Main.js";



    const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        Profile: {screen: Profile},
        Main: {screen: Locatione},
        History: {screen: History},
      }, 
      {
          initialRouteName: "Loading"
      });



      export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Before, I was using createStackNavigator, which was working pretty well. Is there any way that I could combine both CreateBottomStackNavigator and createStackNavigator?

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Auth: Auth,
        Loading: Loading,
        Main:Main,
        Locatione:Locatione,
        Map: Map,
        Contactos: Contactos
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Loading"
    }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default function App() {
    return <AppContainer />;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to add that screen in an navigationStack and name it the inital page, and add the navigation stack to bottomTab navigator.

here im adding the home scren to app stack navigator and this is the inital screen i want to render.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: {
      screen: Home
    },
    AirportMeeting:{
      screen:AirportMeeting
   }

   },

  {
    initialRouteName:"HomeScreen",

  }
  )
```

now im adding that appstack , i.e the stack navigator as a tab in the bottomtab navigator by writing `Home:AppStack` and my notifications and settingscreen are just screens, i.e class componenets

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: AppStack,
  Notification:Notifications,
  Account: SettingsScreen,

})
```

and finally im making my tabnavigator as my appcontainer. hence it works

```
const navigation = createAppContainer(
  TabNavigator
);
```

so similarly you can try for the loadingscreen by adding in the navigation stack and then adding that stack in the bottomTabNavigator  nad creating a container of bottomTabNavigator.
Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, what you basically need to is, create a stack navigator as your app container and inside that put bottom tab navigator. Like,

Something like this,

```
const myTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: YOUR_HOME },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.75
  }
)

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: {
    screen: SplashScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  SomeName: {
    screen: myTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
})
```

You can add any screen you want to show outside bottom tab navigator.